# mysql - SELECT until sum reaches a number

Tags: mysql

I need to select records until the total of a column reaches a variable number.

I have a query that sort of works but not 100%. I also want to see the call_date and I want the count to be done in order of date.

```
SELECT NULL AS inbound_duration, NULL AS total
  FROM dual
 WHERE (@total := 0)
 UNION
SELECT inbound_duration,  @total := @total + inbound_duration AS total
FROM `records` where calling_user = '1' and call_date LIKE '2016-05-%%' and @total < 5000 ORDER BY call_date
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e74ff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this (pay attention: you have two rows with same `call_date`: I think that the order obtained cannot be deterministic, unless you specify other criterias in order by - ex. inbound_duration or some other field):

```
# DROP TABLE records;
CREATE TABLE `records` (
  `inbound_duration` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `call_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `calling_user` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO records
    (inbound_duration, call_date, calling_user)
VALUES
    (100, '2016-05-05 00:00:00', 1),
    (1000, '2016-05-01 00:00:00', 1),
    (900, '2016-05-03 00:00:00', 1),
    (1500, '2016-05-02 00:00:00', 1),
    (2000, '2016-05-04 00:00:00', 1),
    (2500, '2016-05-05 00:00:00', 1)
;
SELECT * FROM records  ORDER BY call_date;


 SELECT NULL AS call_date, NULL AS inbound_duration, NULL AS total
  FROM dual
 WHERE @total := 0 
 UNION ALL
SELECT call_date, inbound_duration,  @total := @total + inbound_duration AS total
 FROM (SELECT * FROM records  ORDER BY call_date) C where calling_user = '1' and call_date LIKE '2016-05-%%' and @total < 5000 

;

DROP TABLE records;
```

Output:

```
    inbound_duration    call_date   calling_user
1   1000    01.05.2016 00:00:00 1
2   1500    02.05.2016 00:00:00 1
3   900 03.05.2016 00:00:00 1
4   2000    04.05.2016 00:00:00 1
5   100 05.05.2016 00:00:00 1
6   2500    05.05.2016 00:00:00 1

    call_date   inbound_duration    total
1   01.05.2016 00:00:00 1000    1000
2   02.05.2016 00:00:00 1500    2500
3   03.05.2016 00:00:00 900 3400
4   04.05.2016 00:00:00 2000    5400
```

Answer (score 0):

order by clause doesn't allow in inside of union query.
To get rid of this,do like below

```
SELECT inbound_duration,total FROM 
(       
SELECT NULL AS inbound_duration, NULL AS total,NULL AS call_date
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE (@total := 0)
 UNION
SELECT inbound_duration,  @total := @total + inbound_duration AS total,call_Date
FROM `records` 
WHERE calling_user = '1' AND call_date LIKE '2016-05-%%' AND @total < 5000 
)t
ORDER BY call_date
```

Comment: thanks but this is only sorting the results i mean i need the sum to be done in order of date

Comment: edit your question with desired result set ,that will be better to get understand

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `union` to initialize your variable. You can use e.g.

```
select * from (
  SELECT inbound_duration, @total := @total + inbound_duration AS total
  FROM `records`, (select @total := 0) init
  where calling_user = '1' and call_date LIKE '2016-05-%%'
  ORDER BY call_date
) subq
where total-inbound_duration < 5000
order by total;
```

Since your dates are not unique, you should add the primary key to your inner `order by`, otherwise you might get unstable results: e.g. for `< 6000`, the result might include or exclude the amount `100`, depending on whether `order by call_date` randomly placed it before or after the row with `2500` on the same date.